# how to change default page to my content while doing local web development using vagrant python flask?

Tags: python, flask, vagrant, localhost, vagrantfile

I'm currently using vagrant and set it up to connect to my local computer's port 5000 and when I move to localhost:5000, the default ubuntu webpage appears to confirm that I'm connected.

However, it tells me to manipulate the app using the index.html in there but I already have a whole Python flask app stored somewhere on github that I want to just git install and run using flask. My flask app works on vagrant because I've tested it out already.

How do I change the pages localhost:5000 is displaying to that of my flask app?

For reference, here's my flask app python code (html templates are in their own folders and didn't include):

```
import os
from angular_flask import app


def runserver():
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    runserver()
```

I've also added this to my vagrantfile

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 5000
```

which allows me to see the pages on my localhost but I want to change the pages viewed to that of the same thing I set up here: https://cs3319asst3.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I've been googling around and the answers tend to just explain creating a server from anew using something like nginx which is not really what I'm trying to do which lead me to post a question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line for forwarding the port in my vagrantfile was wrong, I used the default guest machine port and should have switched it to the port from my flask app.

This is the new line in my vagrant file:

```
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5000, host: 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you're connecting to your localhost, whereas the Flask app is running in your Vagrant VM. You should be connecting to the address of your VM; or, you can forward port 5000 from the VM via the Vagrant settings.

Comment: do you mean adding forwarding to port 5000 to the vagrant file using the below code:
 config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 5000

Comment: I've tried it and it works but I want to change the pages displayed on localhost to that of the ones displayed by my flask app seen here: https://cs3319asst3.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Well you've said "it works", so I don't understand what else you want to do.

Comment: like i want my flask app to display on localhost, not the default "vagrant works and is connected" page

Comment: Then it didn't work. Is the Flask app within Vagrant actually running?

Comment: Yep it tells me its running on port 5000

Comment: I've tried deleting the standard html content in the /var/www folder on my vagrant and just cloning my github repo and running flask in var/www, flask is running (program doesnt terminate from error, etc) and tells me its running but when I move to localhost:5000 it says its 404

Comment: Finally realized the issue, thanks so much for your help though!

I needed to change the port of my guest machine too from default port 80 to port 5000 and i guess i forgot, heres the new line in my vagrantfile:

config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5000, host: 5000